# ¿Como reproducir un sonido en javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

De esta manera.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var snd = new Audio("alarm.wav");
  snd.play();
});
```

Y me lanza el siguiente error:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

Veo otra manera de hacerlo:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  let embed = $('<embed/>',{
    'src' : 'alarm.wav',
    'autostart' : 'false',
    'width' : '0',
    'height' : '0',
    'id' : 'sound1',
    'enablejavascript' : 'true'
  });
  embed.appendTo($('body'));

  function PlaySound(soundObj) {
    var sound = document.getElementById(soundObj);
    sound.Play();
  }
  PlaySound("sound1");
});
```

Y este otro me lanza el siguiente error:

> Uncaught TypeError: sound.play is not a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo de este modo:

HTML5

```
<audio id="audio" controls>
<source type="audio/wav" src="audio.wav">
</audio>
```

CSS

```
#audio{
display: none
}
```

Javascript

```
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");

audio.play();
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: descartando las opciones de click, lo dejo asi: `var audio = document.createElement("audio");
audio.src = "audio.wav";
audio.play();` Pero igual me arroja el primer error que coloque en la pregunta.

Comment: Si esta bien y que raro, si insertas bien la ruta exacta del audio?

Comment: si, esta al lado del archivo **script.js** el cual contiene el codigo q intento ejecutar.

Comment: Modifique la respuesta, intenta así a ver si te funciona.

Comment: Genial hermano, me funciono. Gracias.

Comment: De nada :) te recomiendo esta librería [howler.js](https://howlerjs.com) por si solo quieres hacerlo con javascript, es muy fácil de utilizar y tienes muchos modos de uso.